# How do I move an Eclipse project to a different computer?

Tags: eclipse

I am in an intro computer science course, and Eclipse is used. I usually work on assignments on my laptop, but I'd like to work on my desktop when I am back in my room. However, I don't know how to transfer the project correctly to my desktop because apparently, Eclipse is nothing like Microsoft Word where I can just open it up in a different computer and pick up where I left off.

If I have an unfinished assignment (Eclipse project) on my laptop, and I want to continue working on it on my desktop, how would I copy the project folder over to my desktop?

Answer (score 1):

Depends on things like dependency locations and such, but assuming you're just using the built-ins, it's easy.

Copy the project directory over to the other computer, open eclipse, `file -> import -> existing projects into workspace` and select your directory.

Should work fine.

If you have more dependencies (such as maven-acquired artefacts), I'd recommend using a build/dependency manager like [Gradle](https://gradle.org/)

Answer (score 0):

When I've used Eclipse. After creating a project I would go to open, save as, and add the project to my desktop. You can copy the entire folder and add it to a flash drive to move it to another computer.